# How to save word special symbols into oracle database with jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, character-encoding

I want to insert words special symbols like `≥`, `©`, `£`, ... into oracle database with jdbc connection, but when command execution done completely, it saves `?` character instead of orginal symbol. this is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestSecialChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.251.80:1521:db", "db", "dbadmin");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("get connection failed!");
        }

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        String sql = "insert into test_char " +
                "(fname, description) " +
                "values (?, ?)";

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, "User");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "≥"); // save as ? into database

        try {
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("OK!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Execution failed!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your NLS_CHARACTER_SET

Comment: NLS_CHARACTER_SET = AL16UTF16

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `CHR` function while inserting in oracle

```
INSERT INTO test_chr(fname,description) values (1,chr(172));
```

you can check the values of ascii in oracle

```
select ascii('©') from dual
```

I dont know how to use the same in `preparedStatement`. might be you can check other resource.